# Combine multiple columns to yield unique values

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to use Tableau (v10.1) to combine 5 separate columns and get a count of the distinct values for that combination.  Some rows/columns are empty.  For example:

`+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Tag 1 | Tag 2 | Tag 3 | Tag 4 | Tag 5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | C     | D     | E     |
| B     | D     | E     | -     | -     |
| -     | -     | -     | -     | -     |
| E     | A     | -     | -     | -     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+`

I want to obtain the following in a Tableau worksheet:

`+-----+-------+
| Tag | Count |
+-----+-------+
| E   |     3 |
| A   |     2 |
| B   |     2 |
| D   |     2 |
| C   |     1 |
+-----+-------+`

I would like to do this in Tableau (using calculated fields, etc.) and not change the original data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the data source tab, select the five fields named Tag # and then use the pivot command to reshape the data without changing the original source